# How do I getAbsolutePathBuilder() outside of @Context

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I have a simple JAX-RS app written in Jersey 2.13 which I use to emit "links" using the UriBuilder derived through UriInfo injected via the @Context annotation.

```
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;
...
UriBuilder uriBuilder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
String prId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
URI prURI = uriBuilder.path(prId).build();
...
builder.putLink(new Link("self", prURI.toString()));
```

I find that in some of my supporting classes I need a means of getting a UriBuilder derived from uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder() WITHOUT having the benefit of using the @Context annotation.  How do I do this?  Is there someway I can ask the Resource directly for a builder?  How about statically asking, what, the class that extends ResourceConfig for the builder?

How can I get an getAbsolutePathBuilder() outside of @Context?

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the request in a filter using ContainerRequestFilter and then put the uriInfo object into a thread local variable.  Below is a possible solution, but not 100% complete as I do not provide the UriInfoHolder class that needs to hold a thread-local instance of the uriInfo object.  To see how to do this, you can look at spring's LocaleContextHolder class as an example.

```
@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
            throws IOException {

        UriInfo uriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();
        if (uriInfo != null)
            UriInfoHolder.setUriInfo(uriInfo);

    }
}
```

Then in any of your other classes on the thread invoked by the Resource, you can get the uriInfo (and thus the absolutePathBuilder) by calling method `UriInfoHolder.getUriInfo()`.  See the parallel `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` method for inspiration.

This answers your question, but I would be negligent if I did not point out that IMO best practice would be to the pass the "absolutePathBuilder" into the classes (ideally as part of the service method call) if that information is truly needed by the classes.  Pulling things from the environment as I have shown above often result in hard to find bugs years down the road when new people don't understand how the code works.

Comment: "...that IMO best practice would be to the pass the "absolutePathBuilder" into the classes..." I'm starting to see the wisdom of this.  The @Provider thing doesn't really help my issue, I think "my issue" is actually the problem.